# How do I build a static Go binary for the Docker Alpine image?

Tags: docker, go, alpine-linux

I want to build a Go 1.9.2 binary and run it on the Docker Alpine image. The Go code I wrote doesn't call any C code. It also uses the `net` package. Unfortunately it hasn't been as simple as it sounds as Go doesn't seem to quite build static binaries all the time. When I try to execute the binary I often get cryptic messages for why the binary didn't execute. There's quite a bit of information on the internet about this but most of it ends up with people using trial an error to make their binaries work.

So far I have found the following works, however I don't know why, if it is optimal or if it could be simplified.

```
env GOOS=linux GARCH=amd64 go install -v -a -tags netgo -installsuffix netgo -ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags -static"
```

What is the canonical way (if it exists) to build a Go binary that will run on the Alpine 3.7 docker image? I am happy to use `apk` to install packages to the Alpine image if that would make things more efficient/easier. (Believe I need to install `ca-certificates` anyway.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you often need to add extra resource files like certificates especially when using a minimal distribution like alpine but the fact that you can run go applications on such small distributions is often also seen as an advantage.

To add the certificates this is a really good explanation outlining how to do it on a scratch container:

https://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/

If you would rather stick with alpine then you can install this package to get them:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.7/main/x86/ca-certificates

Comment: The first link helped a lot. This seems sufficient `env GOOS=linux GARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go install -v -a -installsuffix cgo`. The Github issue at https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9344#issuecomment-69944514 shows the solution also.

Comment: Alpine v3.3 is three years old and not supported anymore. You should link the recent version, which is https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.7/main/x86/ca-certificates.