# Dockerfile ERROR: standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm having this error when trying to create service `ERROR: standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory".`. This does not happen when I use ubuntu:latest as base image.

So I try to run service with:

```
docker service create --name mon --publish 9999:9999 --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,destination=/var/run/docker.sock mon:1
```

And the service is not successfully created.

Here is my dockerfile with golang:alpine:

```
FROM golang:alpine
COPY . /edg
RUN chmod a+x /edg/edgmn
EXPOSE 9999
CMD ["/edg/edgmn", "--rules.reactive", "--swarm.environment", "--alert.address=X:9091"]
```

I've tried a lot of things but nothing works.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: "/edg - file not found". Please extract and provide a [mcve], along with the docker comand you ran and its output.

Answer (score 3):

Your binary is likely dynamically linked against one or more libraries that is not available in the alpine image. For example, if your binary is linked to `glibc` (typical if you compiled it on Ubuntu), it will not work in alpine (which uses `musl` instead of `glibc`), but would work with `ubuntu:latest`.

See [How do I build a static Go binary for the Docker Alpine image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366173/how-do-i-build-a-static-go-binary-for-the-docker-alpine-image)

In short, compiling your binary with `CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build <args>` before copying it into the alpine container will often solve the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to know which are the libraries causing problems? Thanks @hmm

Comment: Run `ldd <binary>` to see linked libraries. If run from within the alpine container, it will tell if any libraries are not found. It's best to compile statically (edited my answer with a link).

Comment: linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff2698a000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2866e50000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2866a5f000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f286706f000)
this is the result of ldd. Is the problem caused by any of this libraries?
Thanks @hmm

Comment: GNU `libc` is the obvious one. You might try compiling your binary with `CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build ...` before copying it into the alpine container.

Comment: I can't run from the inside of container, because it is not created.

Comment: You could add `RUN ldd /edge/edgmn` to your Dockerfile if you want to see the output of `ldd` from within the alpine container.

Comment: It works now. But it still might be something wrong because virtual size is 400MB. 300MB bigger than with ubuntu:latest image. It should be smaller. Thanks in advance

Comment: The `golang:alpine` image contains all of the Go tools. You don't need all that to run a static binary. Just use `alpine:latest`.

Comment: Yep. 46MB. Thank you so much! @hmm